# Distinct on the basis of max values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Data :

```html
status    info_id    TDS   r_infos    r_id  place      tq   o_id
"ongoing"   "12332" false   "2878"  "2291"  "LEMIE"     2   "25217"
"ongoing"   "12332" false   "2975"  "2379"  "LEMIE"     2   "25217"
"ongoing"   "12332" false   "3153"  "2527"  "LEMIE"     2   "25217"
"ongoing"   "12463" false   "2650"  "2094"  "CORIO"     1   "25290"
"ongoing"   "12463" false   "2735"  "2167"  "CORIO"     1   "25290"
"ongoing"   "12463" false   "2774"  "2203"  "CORIO"     1   "25290"
"ongoing"   "12463" false   "2878"  "2291"  "CORIO"     1   "25290"
"ongoing"   "12463" false   "2975"  "2379"  "CORIO"     1   "25290"
"ongoing"   "12463" false   "3153"  "2527"  "CORIO"     1   "25290"
"ongoing"   "12465" false   "2774"  "2203"  "SAN  "     1   "25306"
"ongoing"   "12465" false   "2878"  "2291"  "SAN  "     1   "25306"
"ongoing"   "12465" false   "2975"  "2379"  "SAN  "     1   "25306"
"ongoing"   "12465" false   "3153"  "2527"  "SAN  "     1   "25306"
"ongoing"   "12466" false   "2878"  "2291"  "CORIA"     1   "25291"
"ongoing"   "12466" false   "2975"  "2379"  "CORIA"     1   "25291"
"ongoing"   "12466" false   "3153"  "2527"  "CORIA"     1   "25291"
"ongoing"   "12539" false   "2650"  "2094"  "BARBANIA"  1   "25395"
"ongoing"   "12539" false   "2975"  "2379"  "BARBANIA"  1   "25395"
"ongoing"   "12539" false   "3153"  "2527"  "BARBANIA"  1   "25395"
"ongoing"   "12724" false   "2878"  "2291"  "PIOVA"     1   "25593"
"ongoing"   "12724" false   "2975"  "2379"  "PIOVA"     1   "25593"
"ongoing"   "12724" false   "3153"  "2527"  "PIOVA"     1   "25593"
"ongoing"   "12725" false   "2774"  "2203"  "COCCONATO" 3   "25594"
"ongoing"   "12725" false   "2878"  "2291"  "COCCONATO" 3   "25594"
"ongoing"   "12725" false   "2975"  "2379"  "COCCONATO" 3   "25594"
"ongoing"   "12725" false   "3153"  "2527"  "COCCONATO" 3   "25594"
"ongoing"   "12929" false   "2975"  "2379"  "GASSINO "  2   "25875"
"ongoing"   "12929" false   "3153"  "2527"  "GASSINO "  1   "25875"
"ongoing"   "12929" false   "3153"  "2527"  "GASSINO "  2   "25875"
```

Expected :

```html
status    info_id    TDS   r_infos    r_id  place      tq   o_id
"ongoing"   "12332" false   "3153"  "2527"  "LEMIE"     2   "25217"
"ongoing"   "12463" false   "3153"  "2527"  "CORIO"     1   "25290"
"ongoing"   "12465" false   "3153"  "2527"  "SAN  "     1   "25306"
"ongoing"   "12466" false   "3153"  "2527"  "CORIA"     1   "25291"
"ongoing"   "12539" false   "3153"  "2527"  "BARBANIA"  1   "25395"
"ongoing"   "12724" false   "3153"  "2527"  "PIOVA"     1   "25593"
"ongoing"   "12725" false   "3153"  "2527"  "COCCONATO" 3   "25594"
"ongoing"   "12929" false   "3153"  "2527"  "GASSINO "  2   "25875"
```

In above expectation we need to take the max of `r_infos`    group by `o_id`

**Please note : Avoiding the use of `distinct ON`**

Query:

```html
    select distinct  
    epieventin8_.status,

    outbreakin6_.outbreak_info_id as info_id,
    outbreaksp5_.is_wild as TDS,
    report1_.report_id as r_infos,
    reportinfo0_.report_info_id as r_id,
    outbreakin6_.location_name as place, 
    outbreaksp5_.quantities_ncase as tq,
    outbreaks4_.outbreak_id as o_id
    
    
        from get_reports_view reportinfo0_         
        inner join reports report1_ on reportinfo0_.report_id=report1_.report_id
        inner join epi_event epievent2_ on report1_.epi_event_id=epievent2_.epi_event_id 
        inner join outbreaks_for_events outbreaksf3_ on epievent2_.epi_event_id=outbreaksf3_.epi_event_id 
        inner join outbreaks outbreaks4_ on outbreaksf3_.outbreak_id=outbreaks4_.outbreak_id         
        left outer join outbreak_species_quantity outbreaksp5_ on outbreaks4_.outbreak_id=outbreaksp5_.outbreak_id 
        inner join outbreak_infos outbreakin6_ on outbreaks4_.outbreak_id=outbreakin6_.outbreak_id
        left outer join cluster_quantities clusterqua7_ on outbreaks4_.outbreak_id=clusterqua7_.outbreak_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function (`rank()` or `row_number()`) in a derived table, e.g.:

```
select
    status, info_id, TDS, r_infos, r_id, place, tq, o_id
from (
    select *, row_number() over w
    from the_data
    window w as (partition by o_id order by r_infos, tq desc)
    ) s
where row_number = 1
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2e8cdcf2683ab3740d444f46c8fec42a)